# How to transform pandas series into dataframe to merge with other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate number of months for each ID
`number_of_months=df.ID.value_counts()`
and I got pandas series

```
        ID
    564 30
    133 30
    156 30
    153 30
```

with a single column ID

How can I get dataframe `df1` with two columns `(ID, numberofmonts)` to merge with other dataframe `df` based on ID

`df = pd.merge(df, df1,  how='left', left_on=['ID'], right_on = ['ID'])`

That is standard problem for feature engineering. I want to define some new feature with count or other function and then merge with dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of *value_counts()* is in this case a *Series* with:

- index - original *ID* values,
- values - how many times this *ID* occurs in the source *Series*.

A bit tricky detail is that the name of this Series (*ID*) refers actually
to (the only) column, containg the **number of occurrences** of particular
value it the original *ID* column.

So your task is to:

- Rename the index to *ID* (in place).
- Rename the Series itself to *numberOfMonths* or whatever your name of choice
  (also in place).
- Reset the index, saving the result in a target variable. As *drop*
  parameter is left with its default value (*False*), the so far
  existing index becomes an "ordinary" column, keeping its name.

The code to do it is:

```
number_of_months.index.rename('ID', inplace=True)
number_of_months.rename('numberOfMonths', inplace=True)
df1 = number_of_months.reset_index()
```

The result, for your sample data, is:

```
    ID  numberOfMonths
0  564              30
1  133              30
2  156              30
3  153              30
```

Now *ID* name pertains to original *ID* values and you can merge it with
another DataFrame just on *ID* column.

## Alternative solution

If your intention is to add *numberOfMonths* column to *df*,
containing information how many times particular *ID* occurs
in this DataFrame, a quicker and simpler solution is:

```
df['numberOfMonths'] = df.groupby('ID').transform('count')
```